# MakerBot replicator 2x glitches

Tags: filament, makerbot, replicator-dual

I have access to a MakerBot Replicator 2X which I use to try to print ABS + dissoluble (both are MakerBot's original filaments). It is really a pain and the filaments most often gets clogged (80% of the prints have to be thrown away). I a supposed to use the printer in a professional context, but at the moment it is really problematic and I feel pressure going up...

I have initially tried the default parameters provided by the machine for known filaments (ABS: 230°C / dissoluble: 250°C / plate: 110°C + 0.1mm layers). As the nozzle got clogged I have made many other attempts with varying parameters and up to (250°C / 270°C / 135°C), which slightly improves things but is far from being really usable.

Any idea of where this comes from?
 - ABS being notoriously difficult to print?
 - The Replicator 2x being old tech?
 - A parameters problem?

Any advice on what I should do to improve the situation?

Comment: I have one and, you may want to check to make sure that both of the nozzles are at the same height off the build plate when you level. Mine is fairly old so they may have changed how they're installed. I found by adjusting the height of the nozzles to be closer to the same the prints came out more reliably. Mine were off by ~0.3 mm from the factory, and I was able to get them down to about ~0.1mm with a fair bit of playing with them. I hope it helps, but just to be clear this isn't a parameter set in software, this was a physical height that I checked using feeler gauges.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I have tried parameters close to yours (getting inspiration from your parameters file) and with great success so far. It seems to be working now, especially with a reduced speed and higher thickness (as shown in your file). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a profile that has settings for the dissolvable filament anymore, but this is one I use for thin layers (second extruder at 232C my first extruder isn't working so just ignore that one).

You may want to try printing small simple objects with each extruder independently first to confirm that you have good settings, then try both together after you know you have good settings. ABS is a pain but mostly for warping and sticking to the build plate. The dissolvable filament I believe is PLA if you're using Makerbot materials.

```
{
       "_attached_extruders" : [ "mk8", "mk8" ],
       "_bot" : "replicator2x",
       "_extruders" : [ 0 ],
       "_materials" : [ "abs", "abs" ],
       "adjacentFillLeakyConnections" : false,
       "adjacentFillLeakyDistanceRatio" : 0,
       "anchorExtrusionAmount" : 5.0,
       "anchorExtrusionSpeed" : 2.0,
       "anchorWidth" : 2.0,
       "backlashEpsilon" : 0.050,
       "backlashFeedback" : 0.90,
       "backlashX" : 0.0,
       "backlashY" : 0.090,
       "bedZOffset" : 0.0,
       "bridgeAnchorMinimumLength" : 0.80,
       "bridgeAnchorWidth" : 0.80,
       "bridgeMaximumLength" : 80.0,
       "bridgeSpacingMultiplier" : 1.0,
       "coarseness" : 9.999999747378752e-005,
       "commentClose" : "",
       "commentOpen" : ";",
       "computeVolumeLike2_1_0" : false,
       "defaultExtruder" : 0,
       "defaultRaftMaterial" : 0,
       "defaultSupportMaterial" : 0,
       "description" : "External Definition",
       "doAnchor" : true,
       "doBacklashCompensation" : false,
       "doBreakawaySupport" : true,
       "doBridging" : true,
       "doDynamicSpeed" : false,
       "doDynamicSpeedGradually" : true,
       "doDynamicSpeedInteriorShells" : false,
       "doDynamicSpeedOutermostShell" : true,
       "doExponentialDeceleration" : false,
       "doExternalSpurs" : true,
       "doFixedLayerStart" : false,
       "doFixedShellStart" : true,
       "doInfills" : true,
       "doInsets" : true,
       "doInternalSpurs" : false,
       "doMixedRaft" : false,
       "doMixedSupport" : false,
       "doOutlines" : true,
       "doPrintLayerMessages" : false,
       "doPrintProgress" : true,
       "doPurgeWall" : false,
       "doRaft" : true,
       "doSplitLongMoves" : true,
       "doSupport" : true,
       "doSupportUnderBridges" : false,
       "endGcode" : "",
       "exponentialDecelerationMinSpeed" : 0.0,
       "extruderProfiles" : [
          {
             "bridgesExtrusionProfile" : "bridges",
             "feedDiameter" : 1.820000052452087,
             "feedstockMultiplier" : 0.9300000000000001,
             "firstLayerExtrusionProfile" : "firstLayer",
             "firstLayerRaftExtrusionProfile" : "firstLayerRaft",
             "floorSurfaceFillsExtrusionProfile" : "floorSurfaceFills",
             "infillsExtrusionProfile" : "infill",
             "insetsExtrusionProfile" : "insets",
             "layerHeight" : 0.20,
             "maxSparseFillThickness" : 0.20,
             "nozzleDiameter" : 0.40,
             "outlinesExtrusionProfile" : "outlines",
             "raftBaseExtrusionProfile" : "raftBase",
             "raftExtrusionProfile" : "raft",
             "restartExtraDistance" : 0.0,
             "restartExtraDistance2" : 0,
             "restartExtraRate" : 25.0,
             "restartExtraRate2" : -1,
             "restartRate" : 25.0,
             "restartRate2" : 25,
             "retractDistance" : 1.700000047683716,
             "retractDistance2" : 0,
             "retractRate" : 25.0,
             "retractRate2" : 50,
             "roofSurfaceFillsExtrusionProfile" : "roofSurfaceFills",
             "sparseRoofSurfaceFillsExtrusionProfile" : "sparseRoofSurfaceFills",
             "toolchangeRestartDistance" : 18.50,
             "toolchangeRestartRate" : 6.0,
             "toolchangeRetractDistance" : 19.0,
             "toolchangeRetractRate" : 6.0
          },
          {
             "bridgesExtrusionProfile" : "bridges",
             "feedDiameter" : 1.769999980926514,
             "feedstockMultiplier" : 0.9300000000000001,
             "firstLayerExtrusionProfile" : "firstLayer",
             "firstLayerRaftExtrusionProfile" : "firstLayerRaft",
             "floorSurfaceFillsExtrusionProfile" : "floorSurfaceFills",
             "infillsExtrusionProfile" : "infill",
             "insetsExtrusionProfile" : "insets",
             "layerHeight" : 0.20,
             "maxSparseFillThickness" : 0.20,
             "nozzleDiameter" : 0.40,
             "outlinesExtrusionProfile" : "outlines",
             "raftBaseExtrusionProfile" : "raftBase",
             "raftExtrusionProfile" : "raft",
             "restartExtraDistance" : 0.0,
             "restartExtraDistance2" : 0,
             "restartExtraRate" : 25.0,
             "restartExtraRate2" : -1,
             "restartRate" : 25.0,
             "restartRate2" : 25,
             "retractDistance" : 1.399999976158142,
             "retractDistance2" : 0,
             "retractRate" : 25.0,
             "retractRate2" : 50,
             "roofSurfaceFillsExtrusionProfile" : "roofSurfaceFills",
             "sparseRoofSurfaceFillsExtrusionProfile" : "sparseRoofSurfaceFills",
             "toolchangeRestartDistance" : 18.50,
             "toolchangeRestartRate" : 6.0,
             "toolchangeRetractDistance" : 19.0,
             "toolchangeRetractRate" : 6.0
          }
       ],
       "extruderTemp0" : 228,
       "extruderTemp1" : 232,
       "extrusionProfiles" : {
          "bridges" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 40.0
          },
          "firstLayer" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 10.0
          },
          "firstLayerRaft" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 50.0
          },
          "floorSurfaceFills" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 40.0
          },
          "infill" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 40.0
          },
          "insets" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 40.0
          },
          "outlines" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 10.0
          },
          "raft" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 90.0
          },
          "raftBase" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 10.0
          },
          "roofSurfaceFills" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 90.0
          },
          "sparseRoofSurfaceFills" : {
             "fanSpeed" : 0.50,
             "feedrate" : 90.0
          }
       },
       "fixedLayerStartX" : 0.0,
       "fixedLayerStartY" : 0.0,
       "fixedShellStartDirection" : 215.0,
       "floorSolidThickness" : 0,
       "floorSurfaceThickness" : 0,
       "floorThickness" : 1.0,
       "gridSpacingMultiplier" : 1.0,
       "infillDensity" : 0.3000000119209290,
       "infillOrientationInterval" : 90,
       "infillOrientationOffset" : 0,
       "infillOrientationRange" : 90,
       "infillShellSpacingMultiplier" : 0.70,
       "insetDistanceMultiplier" : 1.0,
       "jsonToolpathOutput" : false,
       "layerHeight" : 0.1199999973177910,
       "leakyConnectionsAdjacentDistance" : 0.0,
       "maxConnectionLength" : 10.0,
       "maxSparseFillThickness" : 0.1000000014901161,
       "maxSpurWidth" : 0.50,
       "minLayerDuration" : 5.0,
       "minLayerHeight" : 0.010,
       "minRaftBaseGap" : 0.0,
       "minSpeedMultiplier" : 0.30,
       "minSpurLength" : 0.40,
       "minSpurWidth" : 0.120,
       "minThickInfillImprovement" : 1.0,
       "modelFillProfiles" : {},
       "numberOfShells" : 2,
       "platformTemp" : 110,
       "purgeBucketSide" : 4.0,
       "purgeWallBaseFilamentWidth" : 2.0,
       "purgeWallBasePatternLength" : 10.0,
       "purgeWallBasePatternWidth" : 8.0,
       "purgeWallModelOffset" : 2.0,
       "purgeWallPatternWidth" : 2.0,
       "purgeWallSpacing" : 1.0,
       "purgeWallWidth" : 0.50,
       "purgeWallXLength" : 30.0,
       "raftAligned" : true,
       "raftBaseAngle" : 0.0,
       "raftBaseDensity" : 0.6999999880790710,
       "raftBaseLayers" : 1,
       "raftBaseRunGapRatio" : 0.8000000119209290,
       "raftBaseRunLength" : 15.0,
       "raftBaseThickness" : 0.3000000119209290,
       "raftBaseWidth" : 2.50,
       "raftExtraOffset" : 0.0,
       "raftFillProfiles" : {},
       "raftInterfaceAngle" : 45.0,
       "raftInterfaceDensity" : 0.3000000119209290,
       "raftInterfaceLayers" : 1,
       "raftInterfaceThickness" : 0.2700000107288361,
       "raftInterfaceWidth" : 0.4000000059604645,
       "raftModelSpacing" : 0.3499999940395355,
       "raftOutset" : 4.0,
       "raftSurfaceAngle" : 0.0,
       "raftSurfaceLayers" : 3,
       "raftSurfaceShellSpacingMultiplier" : 0.6999999880790710,
       "raftSurfaceShells" : 2,
       "raftSurfaceThickness" : 0.1400000005960465,
       "roofAnchorMargin" : 0.40,
       "roofSolidThickness" : 0,
       "roofSurfaceThickness" : 0,
       "roofThickness" : 1.0,
       "shellsLeakyConnections" : false,
       "solidFillOrientationInterval" : 90,
       "solidFillOrientationOffset" : -45,
       "solidFillOrientationRange" : 90,
       "sparseInfillPattern" : "hexagonal",
       "splitMinimumDistance" : 0.40,
       "spurOverlap" : 0.0010,
       "startGcode" : "",
       "startPosition" : {
          "x" : -112,
          "y" : -73.0,
          "z" : 0
       },
       "supportAligned" : false,
       "supportAngle" : 30.0,
       "supportDensity" : 0.2000000029802322,
       "supportExcessive" : false,
       "supportExtraDistance" : 0.50,
       "supportFillProfiles" : {},
       "supportLayerHeight" : 0.2000000029802322,
       "supportLeakyConnections" : false,
       "supportModelSpacing" : 0.2000000029802322,
       "supportRoofModelSpacing" : 0.4000000059604645,
       "thickLayerThreshold" : 0,
       "thickLayerVolumeMultiplier" : 1,
       "travelSpeedXY" : 150.0,
       "travelSpeedZ" : 23.0,
       "version" : "3.9.4"
    }
```

Comment: I can already spot heavy differences with my params (ex: travel speed: you go rather slow (40) while the default values I use are much higher (90))... Thanks a lot!